# Codeigniter form_validation callback is never called

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am setting the form rules in my users model and im having a hard time **to reach the is_unique_email callback function**. It never enters the function. All seems to be working fine despite that!

Can anyone help me sorting this issue?

**Users Model:**

```
public function form_rules()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome', 'Nome', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|callback_is_unique_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|matches[password_repeat]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_repeat', 'Repeat Password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function is_unique_email()
    {
        die("asadadaa");
    }
```

**My controller**

```
public function insert()
    {
        if ($this->user_model->form_rules() == FALSE) {
            $this->index();
        } else {
            echo "The form was validated!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not failing the valid e-mail flag first? If it does, it won't ever call your callback. Also, are you aware CI has a flag for checking uniqueness, without needing a callback? `is_unique[]`

Comment: I am new to CI, was not aware. I am using is_unique[] now and it´s working! Thank you for that! :) Anyway, i follow the doc and several other issues with callbacks and still can´t figure it out why is not calling the function! Im affraid to use other callback now!:) And yes the email is valid. He goes straight for the "The form was validated!" message from my controller.

Comment: It simply refuses to die!

Comment: @AndreGarcia try this `$this->form_validation->run($this)`

Comment: @Iain It didn´t work. I prefer to use the rules in my model. Could it be because of that? I like to follow good practices, is that a good practice? I will continue to debug the issue and will inform you when fixed! Thanks!

Comment: @AndreGarcia Worth a shot :) I'm not sure what's recommended on where to have your rules but I've always put my callback rules into the controller.

Comment: Agree with @Iain. Model is for data handling, not for enforcing logic IMO.

Comment: @Utkanos I was on the same impression until I saw Laravel framework (I know we are talking CodeIgniter here; one may argue). Now I put everything separately validation in validation class, database calls in repository class, and controller really does "one line job" to call everything together, no ifs no nothing in controller, custom exceptions are handled in exception class (old school if()s from past).

Comment: @Kyslik - fair enough; I've not used Laravel. What you describe is different from the methodology I'm accustomed to, but if it works and is scalable, then why not.